# Select subset for each item

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using SQL (from a PHP script) to get a list of items from my database, i.e.

```
SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `books` WHERE `removed` = NULL;
```

I also have a table containing articles, with a column `bookId` which refers to the id of the book.

```
SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `articles` WHERE `bookId`=1;
```

Now, I want to prepare a list of all books, and for each book I want to see all related articles (e.g. just the title).

- Book 1

  - Article 1
  - Article 2
- Book 2

  - Article 3

So far, the only way I could image to get such a list is to first perform a query to get all the books, and then for each book to select the related articles. However, this would require a lot of separate SQL calls.

Does anyone have any idea wether it would be possible to get such a list with a single call?

Comment: did you check SQL Joins ? use this url https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp let me know if it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your second SQL query to:

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, 'bookId' FROM `articles`;
```

and then create new array with simple foreach, where $articles is array of results of this query:

```
$articlesByBook = [];
foreach ($articles as $article) {
   $articlesByBook[$article['bookId']][] = $article;
}
```

and then you can access all articles for given book by:

```
$articlesByBook[$bookId]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JOIN,

```
SELECT  a.id,a.title ,b.id,b.title
FROM `books` a
     LEFT JOIN  `articles` b ON b.bookId=a.id
WHERE a.removed IS NULL;
```

Comment: When using join, I will get a long list with duplicate entries, which is more complicated to sort into a list. Therefore, the solution proposed by Michal suits my needs better